# Encounter error when deploy React app to AWS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, testdriven.io

After following TestDriven.io to deploy React code to AWS, I encounter this error:

[image]

This is not an issue in Local. Users API works as well. Only on client part I encounter this error. Any thoughts regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably after the build. either users is undefined or passing null value which .map() cant loop over an array. Try keeping null validation before running .map()

Comment: I have seed the value in DB. Running <ALB_PATH>/users return json of 2 users